# Draw on SurfaceView with Bitmap as background

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-bitmap

In my Android application, I have an image view with a bitmap. I want to be able to draw rectangle or freehand when user touches this image view. I can currently draw these shapes using canvas. However if I use canvas I have to copy the bitmap in image view to a temporary image and then create canvas out of it as follows-

```
 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)closestImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        //need to get the dimensions of scaled bitmap
        alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        //matrix.s
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0,0, paint);
        closestImageView.setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);
```

However after drawing I want to save the image (only the rectangle or freehand lines drawn by user) to a new bitmap. Currently with this canvas method, it saves the original bitmap as well since thats part of the canvas. 
From what I read, it seems Surface View is the right way to achieve this? How can I achieve the functionality that I desire to?

Thanks

AG

Comment: what `SurfaceView` do you mean? i only see `ImageView` in your code...

Comment: I haven't used SurfaceView and have only used ImageView. But can I achieve the desired functionality of deleting only portion of line that I draw on canvas without erasing the background on image view?

Comment: I have no idea what yiu mean,  what is your primaly goal actually?

Comment: What I want to do is this-I have an image view with a bitmap. I want to be able to draw rectangles on bitmap and then save ONLY those rectangles (and not the original bitmap) out to a new bitmap. I also want the functionality where user can select a rectangle and delete it.

Comment: write a custom `View` then, this is the easiest solution

Comment: oh ok. Can you please explain a little bit more on how that can resolve the issue.